# Why do the exported contacts differ from the contacts presented on the Advanced Search using Display Results as Related Contacts?

Tags: search

If you perform an advanced search using the Display Results As Related Contacts feature, the related contacts presented are correct but when you export but the original contacts are exported instead of the related contacts.

I expected that the contacts exported would match the search results, but this is not occurring. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15682

As a bug that affects relatively few people, the core team with their limited resources hasn't allocated someone to investigate and fix this.  If you're a developer or have access to one, this shouldn't be terribly difficult to develop a patch for; alternatively, if you don't have a developer, you may want to submit this to the [paid issue queue](https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue).