# Exported related contact info for contact sub-type

Tags: relationships, export, sub-types

We've got a site (4.6.11)

That has two organisation sub-types ("project" and "project event") there is a relationship between them (event of/ event is).

On running a search of project events, and using exported contacts to download specific project data- the related contacts option in the drop down has no relationship types listed under it.

On the 4.7 demo site, I've created a sponsor of/ supported by relationship between organisation sub types "Sponsor" and "Team", added contacts of each type and linked them with the relationship.

Again, I've tried to export team details with associated sponssor name, and under the related contact option no relationship types are listed.

I've had a quick look and can't find anyone else eon this board experiencing this problemm but woinder if this is related to this issue?https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15682 as reported here [Why do the exported contacts differ from the contacts presented on the Advanced Search using Display Results as Related Contacts?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/why-do-the-exported-contacts-differ-from-the-contacts-presented-on-the-advanced).

On our live sute, I've run a relationship report and that shows the contacts I'd expect. I've not tried the same on the demo site.

Any ideas/ suggestions/ nuggets of wisdom?

Cheers

Craig

After posting all the above,  I though of a potential work round.

I had the notion that if I edited the relationship type to make it available for all organsiations, it may become available for export.

So I amended the relationship type on the live site.

I searched for contact sub type Project Event, chose export contacts and when I chose Record Type "Organisation" the eventof/ event is relationship options were available under select field> related contact info.

I selected the relationship type  event is and display name option, but on export the column was blank. I reset the export to select event of as relationship type and again the column was blank.

So basically that didn't work either.

Don't know if that, sheds light or obscures the options even further.